# Checking if network connection is available in android?

Tags: java, android

```
  public boolean isNetworkConnectionAvailable(){
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
        if(isConnected) {

                Log.d("Network", "Connected");
                return true;

        }
        else{
            checkNetworkConnection();
            Log.d("Network","Not Connected");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It shows cannot resolve connectivitymanager and Networkinfo....Please help..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try rebuilding after cleaning project.. Try adding this directly
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

Comment: Check if your manifest has proper permissions, you should have "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" permission.

Answer (score 2):

Use this method work like charm...

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
      = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
```

}

You will also need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this util method. I created a util class and added this method to it

```
public class Utils {
         /**
         * ******************************************
         * Method to check whether the Internet is Connected
         * ******************************************
         */
        public static boolean IsNetworkConnected(Context context) {
            if (context != null) {
                ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
}
```

you can try this method as

```
boolean isConnected = Utils.IsNetworkConnected(mContext);
```

and before trying, add these permissionsto AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: read the question first!he is not asking for network check method he has problem with ConnectivityManager!

Answer (score 1):

Give permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```